# Use of redox tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at some questions relating to methods of organic oxidation and reduction and I wasn't sure whether to use the [redox](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redox) tag. The tag wiki doesn't specify where it should be used but I have a feeling that it isn't quite the right tag. Maybe `organic reduction/organic oxidation` or perhaps `oxidising agent/reducing agent` would be useful tags to have or should we just use [redox](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redox).

Comment: Personally, I'm *meh* about this. I'll let better people decide on it and I don't have any strong arguments for either the *pro* side or the *con* side. But imagine when this is done and we have a, say, `organic reduction` and it gets 100 questions. Outta that 100, 20 are gonna be mistags, as not everyone knows what the tag is supposed to be conveying, and 70 will have both `redox` *and* `organic reduction`. So someone would pay a visit to meta.chem.SE and writes in big capitalized letters: "ORGANIC REDUCTION TAG RESIDUAL - LET'S BURN IT DOWN" So I say this might bring more troubles than not.

Comment: Over the last year I have occasionally removed the tag `oxidation` or `reduction` and applied [tag:reaction-mechanism] if the question was about the how. Sometimes the `redox` tag will still work, as it is still technically a reduction-oxidation reaction. Admittedly this is not ideal, but the tags should not summarise a question, but merely categorise them. I believe the proposed tags would not make finding questions any easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an organic chemist, I am perfectly comfortable with describing a reaction involving the oxidation of a compound as a redox reaction. In fact, I teach these reactions using the familiar terms of general chemistry. More importantly, tags like `organic reduction` are unnecessary because we have two tags that appropriate cover this subcategory: [redox](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redox) and [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry). The new tags would not help users find other redox questions or other organic chemistry questions. [There are 24 questions using both tags (currently)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redox+organic-chemistry) and probably more organic chemistry questions that could be tagged with `redox`also.

I do not think there would be many cases where a proposed tag like `oxidizing agent` would not also qualify for the `redox` tag. Oxidizing agents are only oxidizing agents when they react in redox reactions. They may have other behavior in other reactions.

> $\ce{HCl}$ is an oxidizing agent in this reaction:

$$\ce{2HCl + Mg -> MgCl2 + H2}$$

> $\ce{HCl}$ is not an oxidizing agent in this reaction:

$$\ce{HCl + NaOH -> NaCl + H2O}$$